# CodeIgniter Captcha is not working

Tags: codeigniter-2, captcha

I am at my wits end and don't know why my code is not working . Everything seems good to me .. I have implemented a captcha in my user review function and added a verification method using callback_ .

The captcha is showing in the view and i have dumped the session data and the input field data and they are both working.

The form validation is also working in case of `captcha` input field but seems like the callback_check_captcha parameter is not working but the function seems fine to me .

Here is my controller

```
function user_review($id = null , $start = 0){


    $check_id = $this->mdl_phone->get_phone_feature($id);
    if ($check_id == null ) {
        $data['phone_model']    =   $this->get_phone_models();
        $data['feature'] = null;
        $data['title']      =   'Nothing Found';
        $data['main_content']= 'phone/error';
        echo Modules::run('templates/main',$data);
    } else{

        $data['phone_model']    =   $this->get_phone_models();

        $data['success'] = null;
        $data['errors'] = null;

        if($this->input->server("REQUEST_METHOD") === 'POST' ){

            $this->load->library('form_validation');

            $this->form_validation->set_rules('text','Review','required|xss_clean');
            $this->form_validation->set_rules('captcha', 'Captcha','trim|required|callback_check_captcha');

            if($this->form_validation->run() == FALSE){
                $data['errors'] = validation_errors();
            }else{

                $user = $this->ion_auth->user()->row();
                $user_id = $user->id;

                $data = array(
                        'phone_id'  => $id,
                        'user_id'   => $user_id,
                        'text'      => strip_tags($this->input->post('text')),
                );

                $this->db->insert('user_review' ,$data);
                $data['phone_model']    =   $this->get_phone_models();
                $data['success'] = 'Your Review has been successfully posted ';
                $data['errors']= null;
            }
        }


        // Initilize all Data at once by $id
        $data['feature']        =   $this->mdl_phone->get_phone_feature($id);
        //$data['rating']           =   $this->mdl_phone->get_user_rating($id);
        $data['user_review']    =   $this->mdl_phone->get_user_review($id , 5 , $start);

        $this->load->library('pagination');

        $config['base_url']     =   base_url().'phone/user_review/'.$id;
        $config['total_rows']   =   $this->mdl_phone->get_user_review_count($id);
        $config['per_page']     =   5;
        $config['uri_segment']  =   4;
        $config['anchor_class'] =   'class="page" ';

        $this->pagination->initialize($config);

        $this->load->helper('captcha');

        $vals = array(
                'img_path' => './captcha/',
                'img_url' => base_url().'captcha/',
                'img_width' => 150,
                'img_height' => 30,
        );

        $cap = create_captcha($vals);
        $this->session->set_userdata('captcha',$cap['word']);

        $data['captcha']        = $cap['image'];

        $data['title']          = $this->mdl_phone->get_phone_title($id)." User Review , Rating and Popularity";
        $data['main_content']   = 'phone/user_review';
        echo Modules::run('templates/main',$data);
    }
}

function check_captcha($cap)
{
    if($this->session->userdata('captcha') == $cap )
    {   
        return true;

    }
    else{
        $this->form_validation->set_message('check_captcha', 'Security number does not match.');
        return false;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The bellow CAPTHA working properly  refer this code

```
$this->load->helper('captcha');
    $vals = array(
        'img_path' => './captcha/',
        'img_url' => base_url() . '/captcha/'
    );
    $cap = create_captcha($vals);
    $data = array(
        'captcha_time' => $cap['time'],
        'ip_address' => $this->input->ip_address(),
        'word' => $cap['word']
    );
    $this->session->set_userdata($data);
    $data['cap_img'] = $cap['image'];
```

I think your image url problem or you are not giving a file permission to the captha folder .